# how to convert listString to List dateTime in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried to calculate max value from list of values. To do this when I press button, I save current time in a list of Strings. but to calculate the max value I need a list of DateTime, but sharedpref can only save listString. So I need to convert my list of string to list of date time.

I search to extract max value ( duration ) between each date of the list.

Example

```
var strList =
  [ '2019-12-03 12:00', 
    '2019-12-03 12:15', 
    '2019-12-03 12:20', 
    '2019-12-03 12:11',
 ]


 Output = 15 minutes
```

I tried this but don"t find solutions

```
DateTime maxDate;
List<String> stringList = [];
List<DateTime> DateList= [];

  load_max_conso() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

      stringList= prefs.getStringList("save_max_list",); 
      DateList = stringList.parse('1974-03-20 00:00:00');
      maxDate = DateList[0];
      DateList.forEach((date){
        if(date.isAfter(maxDate)){
          maxDate=date;
        }
      });
      return maxDate;

    });
  }
```

Edit :

I tried this

```
   dateList1 = [ '2019-12-03 12:30', '2019-12-03 12:20', '2019-12-03 12:22', '2019-12-03 12:23', '2019-12-03 12:21', ];
       dateList2= dateList1.map(DateTime.parse);

      dateList3=dateList2.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

      max = dateList3.fold((max, e) => max.isAfter(e)? max : e);
        min = dateList3.fold((min, e) => min.isAfter(e)? e : min);
       difference='${max.difference(min)}';
```

but dateList3 return null

Comment: you need to use `Iterable.map()` and `Iterable.reduce()` methods, something like: `stringList.map(stringToDateTimeMapper).reduce(maxDateTimeCombineer)`

Comment: `var strList = [
  '2019-12-03 12:15:28',
  '2019-12-03 12:15:48',
  '2010-01-01 12:00:08',
  '2020-01-01 12:00:08',
  '2019-12-03 12:15:38',
];
print(strList.map(DateTime.parse).reduce((max, e) => max.isAfter(e)? max : e));
print(strList.map(DateTime.parse).reduce((min, e) => min.isAfter(e)? e : min));` to be precise

Comment: Thank you, but I think I was not clear ^^ I search to extract max value ( duration ) between each date of the list. Example  var strList = [ '2019-12-03 12:00', '2019-12-03 12:15',]   output = 15 minutes

Comment: the code i gave you prints the newest and the oldest date in the list - so the duration between them is `max.difference(min)`

Comment: like: `var dateList = strList.map(DateTime.parse);
var max = dateList.reduce((max, e) => max.isAfter(e)? max : e);
var min = dateList.reduce((min, e) => min.isAfter(e)? e : min);
print('max: $max, min: $min, diff: ${max.difference(min)}');`

Comment: I tried but the output isn't what i search. for example,  with this list =>   strList = [ '2019-12-03 12:30', '2019-12-03 12:20', '2019-12-03 12:22', '2019-12-03 12:23', '2019-12-03 12:21', ];   with your code I have the difference between max and min , the result is 12:30 ( max) - 12h20(min) = 10.  Problem is that I have other date between and my max gap is not 10 but 12:30 - 12h23 = 7.

Comment: you want the max difference between two dates, right? so it will be the difference between the oldest and the newest, or i am missing something? my code gave you 10 minutes and this is the max difference between two dates - 7 minutes is < 10

Comment: to be me clear if I press button 3 time  [13:10 , 13:15,  13:22]  I will search the max gap between each date to found the max gap . it's not 13:22- 13:10 the max gap because there is intermediate date  (13:15) so I have two gap 13:10 , 13:15  and 13:15,  13:22 but I search max gap, so the result must be  (13:22 -13:15) = 7

Comment: with three date I can calculate easaly each gap until find the biggest but if I have 150 I don't see how  to calculate all gaps between all possibilities

Comment: are they sorted?

Comment: I can add a custom date in the past, so the list is not sorted

Comment: so `sort()` it first and call `fold()` method instead of `reduce()`

Comment: thank you , I have edit my Question with you modification, but it return null when I try to sort()    dateList2.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

Comment: `var dateList = strList.map(DateTime.parse);
var prevElem = dateList.first;
var max = dateList.fold(Duration.zero, (maxDiff, e) {
  var diff = e.difference(prevElem);
  prevElem = e;
  return diff > maxDiff? diff : maxDiff;
});
print(max);`

Answer (score 0):

```
intl.DateFormat format = intl.DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// this is how you should parse it
for (var string in stringList) {
  stringDate.add(format.parse(string));
}
```

or

```
stringDate = stringList.map((string) => format.parse(string)).toList();
```